# Need Tips for Mounting screw-in Slider electrical Boxes

Tags: electrical, remodeling, backsplash, rough-in, old-work

I know they've been around awhile but I'm still kind of new to them. I occasionally have to mount these Allied slider boxes[image] in new and old work situations, and sometimes they go in perfectly with no problems. However, yesterday I couldn't get them straight to save my life.[image] Yesterday was an especially difficult case because the upward angle of the screws and proximity with the countertop made mounting fairly awkward.[image]
I just find it too easy to get one screw slightly off course, and then the slider twists the whole box. This causes the box to telescope forward at odd angles when you try to slide it out later. [image]Once a screw sinks into wood, it really wants to find that same hole again even if I try to readjust away from it. Anyway, I'm  looking for tips from anyone who knows what I'm talking about.[image]How do you get these things dead on, every time?

Comment: Your last 2 images appear to be identical, did you mean to upload something else?

Comment: yes, thank you. I've swapped the duplicate out and added another view.

Comment: I think I need to find some of these! They're certainly not at my local big-box. Those look _so_ much easier to use and adjust than either nail in new work or "wing-and-flange" old work boxes.

Comment: @FreeMan, thanks for the ideas. The boxes are a bit tricky in some locations but I'm finding they aren't bad if I am able to hold them firmly in place with one hand and run the impact driver with the other. I think I need to find a clamp of some kind to act as a third hand if I ever have to use the right angle attachment again (which requires two hands just to operate). The boxes are nice for tight places where it's difficult to drive nails, and they slide out to the extra depths of layered finish, such as tiled backsplash. Another con: the slider sometimes hinders wide devices such as dimmers

Answer (score 1):

Use a small angle head drill and drill pilot holes - as you say the screw follows the existing hole.

Comment: I could see sacrificing one as a "starter" piece by pulling the slider out and removing the screws so you've got the spacing and the alignment right. Of course, you may be able to do that, then reinsert the sliding piece and the screws and not have to sacrifice the box at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that, as with many things, it just takes practice. If you do it enough times you will learn just how much to hold the box proud of the wall surface when starting the screws - knowing that the screws will tend to pull the box into the wall cavity some as they tighten down.

When working in less than optimal positions such as under a counter it takes some additional skills as a contortionist and knowing when to bring in additional lighting.